# Correctly Mapping viewmodel to entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have my entity as:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I have my UserViewModel as

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am using these as below in my controller:

```
//This is called from my view via ajax
 public void Save(UserViewModel uv)
 {
    // this throws error: cannot convert from UserViewModel to Entity.User
    MyRepository.UpdateUser(uv);
 }
```

My UpdateUser in repository class is as below:

```
  public void UpdateUser(User u)
  {        
   var user = GetUserDetails(u.Id);

    user.Name = u.Name;
    user.Address = u.Address;

   //using entity framework to save
  _context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

How can I correctly map UserViewModel in my controller to my entity

Comment: I think the correct way is using AutoMapper as I described below, see my answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) you can do something like:

```
 public void Save(UserViewModel uv)
 {
    // this throws error: cannot convert from UserViewModel to Entity.User
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

                cfg.CreateMap<UserViewModel , User>();

            });
    User u = config.CreateMapper().Map<User>(uv);
    MyRepository.UpdateUser(u);
 }
```

Or manually :

```
 public void Save(UserViewModel uv)
 {
    User u = new User()
      {
        Id = uv.Id
        Name = uv.Name;
        Address = uv.Address;
      };
    MyRepository.UpdateUser(u);
 }
```

Which is not good to do it manually if you change your view-model and your model then you should change your code also, but with `Automapper` you don't need to change the code.

**EDIT1:**

This is not good idea to use model-view in repository (DataAccess Core) so it would be better to keep your `public void UpdateUser(User u)` and don't change it, in outside it is better to pass `user` to `UpdateUser` not `UserViewModel` like what you have done before.

**EDIT2:**

In my opinion non of answered posts doesn't related to SOC (Separation on concerns) even mine...

1- When I passed `UserViewModel` I've violated the SOC ....

2- In the other side if I got User in Peresentation layer directly I also violated the SOC.

I think the best way is a middle layer as proxy....

Presentation <----> Proxy <----> Repository.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the mapping of property values(view model->enity model) inside your repositories `UpdateUser` method. So use the view model class (`UserViewModel`) as the parameter type of that.

```
public void UpdateUser(UserViewModel  u)
{        
    // Get the entity first
    var user = GetUserDetails(u.Id);

    // Read the property values of view model object and assign to entity object
    user.Name = u.Name;
    user.Address = u.Address;

    //using entity framework to save
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now from your `Save` method ,you can pass the view model object to this method.

This will fix your compile time error (*which is your current problem in the question*), but be careful about what classes you are using in what layers. If you are too much worried about using a view model class in your data access layer, you can do that in a middle service layer. But then you are getting the entity model in that layer and doing the update there.

Remember, **there is no definite answer for that question**. **Use the approach you think is  readable and consistent with the project/ team.** Often times, i tend to use the term "Common DTO classes" than "View models" so i can peacefully pass those around to another layer.  I keep them in a separate project (called **Common DTO**) and this will be cross cutting across other projects. That means i will add a reference to this Common DTO project in my Web/UI layer and my data access/service layer and use those as needed.

Comment: UpdateUser method is in my repository class which is a part of mu Data project and UserViewModel is a part of webproject. I dont think this is the correct way as you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes. So it is a call you have to make youself. Which classes goes until which layer ( There is no definite answer for this question). My answer is to resolve your current compile time error. It is up to you to decide which classes should which layer. Often times, i call the classes Common DTOs instead of view model , which will allow me to pass it to the deep layers.

Comment: I tend to move those common DTO classes to a separate DTO project and have it referred in both the web and data access projects.

Comment: I disagree with this approach. The UserViewModel is clearly meant to facilitate the MVC infrastructure and as such, belongs to the Presentation layer. The repository does not need to have any knowledge of presentation artifacts. It should only deal with the objects it is equipped to handle.

Comment: I also disagree if you passed `ViewModel` to repository then SOC will be violated, Repository shouldn't no anything about Presentation layer and vice versa.See my answer also...

Comment: I agree that repositories should not know about presentation or vice versa. So i tend to have a middle layer. The answer is to fix the error the OP was having. Regarding the layers /terminology, it is really an opinionated world. Everyone has their own opinion (based on the context)

Comment: @Shyju Yes this is really experimental, I mentioned in the post it is better to have middle layer to proxy response and request , and use DTO's to pass data between Presentation and Core by this presentation and Core don't know anything about each other...

Comment: Yes. That is my preferred approach as well (it is as part of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your repository deals with objects of type `User`, so you need to map the values back to an instance of that type and then make the call.

Assuming you have a method to get the user called `GetUser`:

```
public void Save(UserViewModel uv)
{
    var user = MyRepository.GetUser(uv.Id);
    user.Name = uv.Name;
    user.Address = uv.Address;
    MyRepository.UpdateUser(user);
}
```

You can then save the changes in your repository class. You can attach the object to make sure there are no issues if the object was created in a different context:

```
public void UpdateUser(User u)
{      
    _context.Users.Attach(u);
    _context.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Why `user` should be retrieved in `Save` while it can be passed as `UserViewModel `..

Comment: @Aria: The `UserViewModel` class belongs to the Presentation layer. The repository should not have any knowledge of user views. Separation of concerns.

Comment: Yes SOC says that, but repository don't know about presentation layer, if he used Id instead of `UserViewModel` then your sentences and code would be closer.

Comment: The repository **WILL** know about the presentation layer if you pass it the `UserViewModel` class.