# Is it good to use DTOs in all layers with Data Contracts?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm in confusion that I should use DTOs with data contracts (data contracts for security to stop exposing some properties) in all layers(PL, BL and DL) when we're using ADO. Net to communicate with database.
Or better to have two different models one to map data from database and then use mapper to map in view model.
Please help with some pros and cons for both the approaches. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to maintain a set of DTOs that you want to expose to the outside consumers. One good reason to do this is you can tailor what you expose to the consumers.

Another reason to do so is to isolate the DTOs in its own project within the solution. You can then make a NuGet package out of that one project.

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer here [Correctly Mapping viewmodel to entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994080/correctly-mapping-viewmodel-to-entity/47994166#47994166)
it is mentioned why using `DTO` between different layers is useful, but in details below descriptions defining when you should use `DTO`:

1- **Teams** with more than 5 people. Starting with this size, teams will split up and architecture needs to take this into account (just a side note: the phenomenom that the architecture of a system corresponds to the structure of the development team is called [Conway´s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Conway%27s_Law&oldid=360499017)). If teams split up, the tight coupling between back-end and presentation is in-acceptable, so we need `DTOs` to prevent this.

2- **Teams** that work distributed at several locations. The worst-case examples are projects that use some kind of near-shoring or offshoring models.

3- **The** need for complex mapping functionality between domain model in the back-end and the presentation layer.

4- **Average** skilled team, you have junior developers or web-only developers in your team. The usage of `DTOs` allows them to use the back-end services as a "black-box".

5- **Reduce** overhead between back-end and presentation. `DTOs` can be optimized for certain service calls. An optimized `DTO` contains only those attributes that are absolutely required. Popular examples are search services, that return lists of slim `DTOs`. In fact, performance optimization is often the one and only argument to introduce `DTOs`. IMO, this factor is often overemphasized. It may be very important for "real" internet applications that produce a very high load on the back-end. For enterprise systems, one should carefully consider all pros and cons before introducing `DTOs` on a wide scale in an architecture "just" for performance reasons. Maybe it is good enough to optimize just the top 3 search services using specialized DTOs and use domain objects in all over services (especially the CRUD services).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can use DTOs when you need it. It doesn't matter on which layer of your architecture you are, a DTO is an abstraction of concept, mostly used when you hit a service to transfer only the representation of the data you need. There is nothing wrong of exposing your Dtos as part of the contracts. Choose a correct representation for each operation you (a dto for each return you consider) to minimize the amount of properties you want to expose to the consumer. This questions doesn't have nothing to do with security unless you expose sensitive information as part of your Dtos. Even in REST where you don't have contracts, you need to specify a content-type which tells the back end the data representation you need. 
As a consumer of a service there is nothing wrong to expose a dto. 
If you see in your  Data Layer  you should have entities that you use to map directly with the database, maybe using the FirstName, Last Name as columns but that is  data representation on that layer, on your Business Layer maybe you represent those properties as FullName(FirstName+Last Name). My point is that every layer could have a different representation of the data and that is not wrong. Your top layer is the one that returns or receives the DTOs. But you can have as many layer as you want with different representations. 
The cons I am seeing is that evertime you transfer an object from one layer to another you need to map all the properties to your new representation, and that operation can have an impact on the performance of your application. 
As a developer another cons is that to understand your architecture is mandatory to understand your abstractions(including the Dtos) on each layer. If you simplify or remove layers, more readable will become your code in terms of the business logic.
Hope this helps